# @ActionLink with Enum value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a value for enum but not working properly:

Note the following works fine:

```
@Html.Action("CreateInfoLink", "Info", new { id = (int)Info.Document0 })
```

But if "Document0" is stored in a variable, I am not sure how to incorporate it.
Say x.EnumName stored "Document0", how would I incorporate that?

I tried:

```
 @Html.Action("CreateInfoLink", "Info", new { id = (int)Info.(x.EnumName)})
```

but I get a message saying: identifier expected

Comment: Do you mind showing `Info.Document0` enum? And what was that `x`?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
 @Html.Action("CreateInfoLink", "Info", new { id = (int)x.EnumName })
```

Unless you mean that it is stored as the string "Document0".  In which case try this

```
@{ 
    Enum.TryParse(x.EnumName, out Info theEnum);
}

 @Html.Action("CreateInfoLink", "Info", new { id = (int)theEnum })
```